# Does this mean I'm not a team player?

Tags: interviewing

After going through an interview which I thought I did pretty well, I received from HR the following review (an excerpt):

"Also, the team felt you made a lot of assumptions when going into the prioritization challenge and technical assignments"

After giving some thought on it, I realized that the team could possible thought that I'm not a team player, since I tried to fumble myself with the assignments and didn't ask for directions...

Does this mean I am not a team player?

Comment: What was the prioritization challenge? In summary what did you tell them?

Comment: @user814064 the challenge was comprised of 5 options of how would I deal with problems happening in a e-commerce website in production. Since the website was live, what should I work on first to solve the issues...

Comment: It would be interesting to find out, in general terms, what you suggested, for example did you say? 1) Determined impact on users 2) Prioritize issues. etc.

Answer (score 5):

I think you probably made a lot of assumptions when going into the prioritization challenge and technical assignments.

Seriously, what that means is you were jumping to conclusions and not asking questions to make sure you understood the situation properly. In a work situation, if you start trying to solve a problem before you fully understand it, then you risk solving the wrong problem and wasting a lot of time. That makes you less productive, and a less effective worker.

It's nothing to do with being a team player.

Comment: how could I have avoided that? any tips?

Comment: Make sure you understand the problem completely before you start solving it. Even if you think you understand it, try saying "so just to check I understand this" and restate it in your own words. Also think about what they might not be telling you that might make a difference.

Comment: gee... and I thought I was demonstrating how good a independent thinker I was. Talk about self-delusion. Nevertheless, how can I improve on this, since it is a thought pattern I'm so used to that I can't even realize it...

Comment: And tehse types of interview questions are often deigned deliberaltely with big gaping holes to see if you will ask for clarification. This is important in many organizations because they want developers who will push back rather than make unqwarrented assumptions when something is unclear.